# Android: How to get absolute file path using base path and relative with ".."?

Tags: android

I have seen a lot of similar questions here, but none of them addressed my situation:

I created playlist file in some directory (let's say /Music/Playlists/playlist.m3u) on sdcard.
Creating playlist with WMP I get files' paths like below:
../Music/my_music_file.mp3

To sum up, I have:

- base path /Music/Playlists/
- relative path ../my_music_file.mp3
- I want to easily get path of /Music/my_music_file.mp3

How can I easily get files absolute path from something like that?

Comment: post your answer as an answer to your question, not as an edit to it.

Answer (score 0):

That's the simple solution I came up with, in case anyone gets the same problem

```
if (path.startsWith("../")) {
    File dir = new File(base.getPath());
    while (path.startsWith("../")) {
        path = path.substring(3, path.length());
        dir = dir.getParentFile();
    }
    path = new File(dir, path).getPath();
}
```